# How to perform an action by selecting an item from ListView in JavaFX 2

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I would like to have an action performed when I select an item from my `listview` in javafx 2.
I use a Netbeans JavaFX fxml application and SceneBuilder.
The `OnMouseClicked` method in SceneBuilder did not work. It gave me back an error that it can't find the method that I have already declared.

Can someone tell me how they managed to get it to work?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You cannot do it in FXML file alone.
Define the corresponding listView (assuming `fx:id="myListView"` in FXML) in Controller class of the FXML file:

```
@FXML
private ListView<MyDataModel> myListView;
```

Add listener in init/start method which will listen to the list view item changes:

```
myListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<MyDataModel>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends MyDataModel> observable, MyDataModel oldValue, MyDataModel newValue) {
        // Your action here
        System.out.println("Selected item: " + newValue);
    }
});
```

`MyDataModel` can be your own data structure model class or simply a `String`.
For String example,

```
@FXML
private ListView<String> myListView;

...
...

ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList("chocolate", "blue");
myListView.setItems(data);

myListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        // Your action here
        System.out.println("Selected item: " + newValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank You for the fast answer. But I have issues with MyDataModel. I tried it as a String.. like String a = "test"; and ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "chocolate", "blue"); Both didn't work for me.. it asks for a class.. Can You give me an example please?

Comment: Both worked for me, with String and with MyDataModel. For the model I also added a toString() override.