# Getting information about a cell in a javafx listview

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have a Listview, made with Fxml and elements within it were added via an observable list. I want to, when the user double clicks a node, to **get data about that node**. I already dealt with the double click and everything else, but I need to get the name of the clicked node to be able to get data from a hashmap and so on... I tried to use `if(e.getTarget() == ListCell)` but it tells me "Expression expected" as if it was an enum.

I know there might be a duplicate of this somewhere, but I couldn't find any with my formulation of the question... So, I'm asking you, how do I get the name of the node and check if the click happened on a node or in the "void of the listview".

Edit: By name, I mean display name.

Comment: have you tried `list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()`;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459086/how-to-perform-an-action-by-selecting-an-item-from-listview-in-javafx-2

Comment: Unless you define a variable of the same name, `ListCell` is a type and not an object; you cannot use the `==` operator. `instanceof` can be used to check the type of an expression...

Comment: @Sedrick this doesn't fix my problem... When a user selects an item in the list, they can double click anywhere else to still trigger the action... I only want the action to be done if the click happens on an item.

Comment: @fabian you're right, but `instanceof` triggers everytime I click anywhere on the listview, not only an item.

Comment: something wrong in the code you are not showing .. my crystal ball is cloudy ;) Seriously, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish what I think you are asking. This uses `setOnMouseClicked` in the `setCellFactory`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewExperiments extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle("ListView Experiment 1");

        Label label = new Label("Hello World!");

        ListView<Person> listView = new ListView();
        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Person>()
        {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty)
            {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setOnMouseClicked(null);
                }
                else {
                    setText(item.getFirstName() + " " + item.getLastName());
                    setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                        if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && ! isEmpty()) {
                            label.setText(item.getFirstName() + item.getLastName());
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });

        listView.getItems().add(new Person("a", "b"));
        listView.getItems().add(new Person("c", "d"));
        listView.getItems().add(new Person("e", "f"));

        VBox vBox = new VBox(listView, label);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 300, 120);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that, still triggers when double clicking the white part (Where there are no items)

Comment: playing guessing games about what the OP really wants and what gets wrong is ... wasting time, imo

Comment: @EtiennePoulin Just change the condition in the `if` statement in the mouse handler to `if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && ! isEmpty()) { ... }`.

Comment: That did it... @kleopatra sorry I'm really new to stackoverflow... Will read that article and try my best to make a better post next time...