# How to add a listener to a ListView

Tags: java, listview, listener, addition

I would like to have a little script executed every time the content of my ListView is modified, yet there is no way to add a listener to the listView directly. I feel like there should be a solution that's not that complicated.

Edit : I'm working with javaFX, and I have a ListView that contains some objects, the thing is that I want the front colour to change when a propriety of these objects changes. The problem is that the ListView is created in a static method, and its content is directly linked to an attribute of another instance of another class the following way :

```
ListView<Ticket> tiickets = new ListView<>(otherClass.getTicketsInHand());
```

I've tried adding a listener to each element the following way

```
tickets.getItems().forEach(ticket -> {otherClass.isFullyDone(ticket).addListener(...)});
```

yet, with the help of the debugger I've realized that my program never even gets into the body described in the forEach. When this method is called the content of ListView tickets is null, so that's why the listeners are never called upon the elements that are later added. I'm searching for a way to keep thee program updated if elements are ever added and in this case execute the forEach loop.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Add a mention or tag of your GUI framework (Swing, JavaFX, SWT, Vaadin, etc.)

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12459387/2478398)?

Answer (score 1):

A JavaFX ListView is based on an `ObservableList` in your case you get the list using `otherClass.getTicketsInHand()`, so you simply need to add a listener to that list that will run your code. For example:

```
otherClass.getTicketsInHand().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Ticket> c) {
        if(c.next())
            otherClass.getTicketsInHand().get(c.getFrom()).addListener(...);
    }
});
```